# Messages older than 1 year in MS Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007

How can I determine the number and size of messages older than 1 year in MS Exchange 2007?

Answer (score 4):

You can't, sorry.

Exchange provides no capability to globally query mailbox databases for their content; you can configure managed folder policies to automatically move/delete messages that match certain criteria, but you can't ask Exchange questions like the one you posted (unless maybe some third-party product provides such a feature).